# Methods and data value doesn't access to keydown listener Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code in my mounted function :

```
 mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37 :
          alert(this.indexPictures)
          break
      }
    })
  }
```

My data value :

```
  data: function () {
    return {
      indexPictures: this.index,
    }
  },
```

My result : undefined

I don't know why but I can't get value in data function
and this is the same problem, from methods access.
My result : is not a function

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: As you already have a `index` property then I don't think assigning it to an another variable (`indexPictures`) make sense. You can directly access `this.index` wherever required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what `this.index` is but I will assume it is a prop or something similar.

Try removing the keyword `function` from the `addEventListener`.

```vue
 mounted () {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=> {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37 :
          alert(this.indexPictures)
          break
      }
    })
  }
```

It is not particularly relevant to the problem, but remove the `function` keyword from data as well:

```vue
data() {
    return {
      indexPictures: this.index,
    }
  },
```

The keyword `function` changes the scope, meaning `this` is bind to the function itself (in your case the callback).
When you use an arrow function `this` keyword will be the same as in `mounted` - which means you can access your data.

From MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#call_apply_and_bind):

> Perhaps the greatest benefit of using Arrow functions is with methods like setTimeout() and EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener() that usually require some kind of closure, call, apply or bind to ensure that the function is executed in the proper scope.

Keep in mind if this is a part of a component it is a good idea to remove that listener before destroying the component.